# How can I block application fron running on iOS as service

Tags: ios, service, background-process

On android I can create service that check the launch application package name. If it in my block list the service will kill that process.

On iOS how can I do that. 
I can only think to my run the app as background process but I don't know how to kill launching application if it match the blocking list.

Thank you.

Comment: which application you want to kill

Comment: Is this for jailbroken devices?

Comment: @Retro The application that in the list of my block list program.(Ex. Line, Facebook, Safari, Angry Bird, ... etc)

Comment: @Wain It's non jail break device.

Comment: that's not possible in ios without jailbreak

Comment: I see there is restriction section in iPhone setting. Can I pragmatically set those setting ?

Comment: iOS app does not allow to set permission by self and can not change the settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-jailbroken apps you have no access to other processes running on the device and no capability to allow / deny anything at a system level.

Anything like this you did try to do would certainly not be permitted in the app store.

Comment: Thank for the answer.
I understand that this kind of program would against the apple rule. 

But let's say I have jailbroken device can you suggest me how to do it? A hint is OK. (For my reference)

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know, I haven't tried. If you need to know then you should tag the question with the jailbreak tag so appropriate people see it.